# Google Play Developer Console - Delete a game service

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api, google-console-developer

I want to do some cleaning in my *Google Play Developer Console* by deleting
a game service which has currently two linked apps (one for debug and the other for the release). This game service was published by mistake and now, I get this message which never changes :

> Publishing of your game in progress...

I don't see any delete button in the *Google Play Developer Console* and the corresponding project has been already successfully deleted on https://console.developers.google.com.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot delete the application once you have published it in Google Play. Google will keep all the apk files.

The Delete button only works for unpublished version of your app. Once you published your app pr a particular version of it, you cannot delete it from the Market. However, you can still unpublish it.

You may use this as your reference: http://www.cynosurex.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Java/Android/Tips_and_Tricks_for_Uploading_Apps_to_Google_Market

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I haven't published my app (the apk files), I have published a game service (second tab on the left of the _Google Play Developer Console_) which is now linked to "Unknown Project" because as I said, I deleted the corresponding project in the other console, on  : console.developers.google.com

Comment: My problem is now resolved, I had to contact the Google Play Developer support.